# Google analytics date in-page inconsistent

Tags: google-analytics

I've a page with 3 link like

```
    <a href="/abc/a" id="a">LINK 1</a> 
    <a href="/abc/b" id="b">LINK 2</a> 
    <a href="/abc/c" id="c">LINK 3</a>
```

I wanna see in "in-page" view how many click I've done in each Atag.
I've a JS that simulate this click because I made an ajax-call to replace a content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(evn){
        evn.preventDefault();
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $(this).attr("href")]);
        //ajax call 
    });             
});
```

I've clicked 10 times #A link, 20times #B link and 30times #C link. 
In page view I have exactly 10-20-30, but in "in-page" view I've 4.2% with 1 click link #A, 4.2% with 1 click link #B and 17% with 4 click link #C.
why? I want see in in-page view a bubbles that tell me 10 click for #A, 20 click for #B and 30 click for #C

Comment: Run your test function again, this time with a proxy like fiddler or chromes network tab opened and see if there are actually 60 tracking calls sent to the google server. Plus it might take a few hours before data is displayed correctly.

Comment: when I run this test I've opened network tab and I saw all 60 tracking calls